# Codeigniter RESTful API server not returning special characters in URL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this application where I use Codeigniter as Backend and BackboneJS as frontend. So to show data I use the Restserver from Phil Sturgeon. In this case users can click a letter to get artists displayed. Now, since I use the danish alphabet i have an issue displaying danish characters in my URL -> I get 404 error.

So I tried to add this to my config.php in Codeigniter:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'æ ø å a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

And in my root index.php I added some kind of hack:

```
'artists\/[a-zA-Z]',
'artists\/[øØ]',
'artists\/[æÆ]',
'artists\/[åÅ]',
'artists\/0-9',
...etc
```

but still, this doesnt work. I get the 404 page not found error and my network tab in the inspector tool always tells me `%C3%A6`...

My API with the MySQL-query looks like this:

```
public function letter_get($letter)
    {
        $this->load->database();

        if($letter == '0-9')
        {
            $where = "formated_name LIKE '0%' OR formated_name LIKE '1%' OR formated_name LIKE '2%' 
            OR formated_name LIKE '3%' OR formated_name LIKE '4%' OR formated_name LIKE '5%' OR formated_name LIKE '6%' OR formated_name LIKE '7%' OR formated_name LIKE '8%' OR formated_name LIKE '9%' OR formated_name LIKE '#%'";
        }
        else 
        {
            $where = "formated_name LIKE '".$letter."%'";
        }

        $sql = "SELECT artist_id, formated_name FROM artists WHERE ".$where;
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $data = $query->result();

        if($data) {
            $this->response($data, 200); 
        } else {
            $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any artists with this letter!'), 404);
        }
    }
```

So maybe i have to add something here?

Is there anyone who knows what to do here?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: did you try to debug it, what actually letter_get get after the request? Try using $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);

Comment: where should I put it?